# How to convert this type code into laravel form?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar

```
if($type == 'fetch')
{
    $events = array();
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar");
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
    $e = array();
    $e['id'] = $fetch['id'];
    $e['title'] = $fetch['title'];
    $e['start'] = $fetch['startdate'];
    $e['end'] = $fetch['enddate'];

    $allday = ($fetch['allDay'] == "true") ? true : false;
    $e['allDay'] = $allday;

    array_push($events, $e);
    }
    echo json_encode($events);
}
```

This code is about the normal php code, i want to put into laravel controller but it doesnt work. My question is want to ask about how to make this code function and link with my database.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'POST', // Send post data
        data: 'type=fetch',
        async: false,
        success: function(s){
            json_events = s;
        }
    });
```

This is my view code, could anyone help me and show me how to link with it? So i can fetch the data from my database and display it on my fullcalendar.

---

After edited..
This is my View code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{url('events/add')}}',
            type: 'POST', // Send post data
            async: false,
            success: function(s){
                json_events = s;
            }
        });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        });

    });

</script>
```

This is my EventsController

```
  public function show(Request $request){
        if($request->get('type') == 'fetch'){
            return Events::select(['calendar_id','calendar_title','startdate as start', 'enddate as end'])->get();
        }

    }
```

Comment: you can use eventSources option to load events from your server.
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventSources/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as you are using `POST` method & I suppose you are `csrf` middleware globally so whenever you will request `POST` method you will have to pass `csrf` token along with your request. To do that you can add `csrf` token to meta

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

& in your jQuery code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});
```

You can check more details https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection

Now in your jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'YOUR_URL_TO_POST',
    type: 'POST', // Send post data
    data: 'type=fetch',
    async: false,
    success: function(s){
        json_events = s;
    }
});
```

Now in your controller action

```
public function your_method_name(\Request $request)//put your action name & inject Request
{
    if ($request->get('type') == 'fetch')//check type
    {
        return Calendar::select(['id', 'title', 'startdate as start', 'enddate as end', 'allDay'])->get();//I think you have a calendar model
    }
}
```

You can check https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models here on how to define model.

Comment: I not understand about the csrf that you mention in above, is that need to put in my view or?

Comment: `Route::get('events/show','EventsController@show');
`I set my route like this, so in url part, i just put `url:"{{url('events/show')}}` , Like this?

Comment: @Ben if you see `Kernel.php` in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file you will see a `$middleware` protected property. Here all the middleware which will execute in every request is listed. There is a middleware called `VerifyCsrfToken` it's task is to check `csrf`. You should read through laravel documentation more https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection